# If the Rank of [A - B], where A and B are m x m matrix, is not full then there exist a matrix $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ [A-B ] = 0. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am trying to solve a singular linear system, where

$A y_{t+1} =  B y_{t} + C x_t$ where y (m x 1) is endogenous variables and x(n x 1) are exogenous variables. The condition for solution to exist is [Az-B] $\neq$ 0 identically in $z$. Image gives the logic behind putting such a condition. I want to understand the reason why the $\alpha$ exists.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, understood. Thanks.